# Script In Html Won't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add JavaScript in my HTML document, but it doesn't work at all. Below is my full code. The JavaScript works in jsfiddle. I tried to add the script to the end of `<body>`, but that also didn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
<title>Merhaba Dünya!</title>
<script>
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function() {
sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function(e) {
x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));

$("#scroll").css({
'marginLeft': x + 'px'
});
});

</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ornek.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder"><ul id="scroll">
<li><div class="si"></div></li>
<li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
<li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
  <li><div class="si"></div></li>
  <li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
  <li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>

</ul>
</ul></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css

```
#holder {
    background: pink;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#scroll{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#scroll li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.si{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:black;
  float:left;
  border-radius:150px;
  margin:10px;
}
.si:hover{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  margin:2px;
}
```

Comment: At the point when this executes, `<body>` does not exist yet, `#scroll li` doesn't exist, and `$("#scroll li").each` iterates zero times. If you move it to the end of the body this problem disappears; if it is still not working, you should post *that* code, as you then have some other problem.

Comment: Jquery.js include in head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include JQuery in your code. Just add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` before your script tag. JSFiddle might automatically load JQuery for you while your page won't.